# There is a Collection which can I hold a String and an Integer with repetead values?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

I have an text and I will do some filtering based in the number of the words of each phrase.

I was thinking in using a Map, in the key I put the phrase, int the value, the quantity of the words, iterate on the Map and remove the lines that have minor value than something previous specified.

- There is a **map where can I hold repeated entries** (the phrase and the quantity)?
- Can I retrieve from the map in the order I have placed the elements? This is because is a text, so the order of the phrases is important.

**EXAMPLE**

**Original Text**

`My name is Renato | 4

Today is Tuesday | 3

I live in Brazil | 4

My name is Renato | 4

20 years | 2

StackOverflow is a fantastic website | 5`

*Filtering removing phrases with less than 4 words*

**Final Text**

`My name is Renato

I live in Brazil

My name is Renato

StackOverflow is a fantastic website`

Answer (score 3):

> There is a map where can I place repetead entries (the phrase and the quantity)?

Why not have

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> wordCountToStringsMap
```

> Can I retrieve from the map in the order I have placed the elemets? This is because is a text, so the order of the phrases is important.

- [`LinkedHashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

Comment: Because if he uses a `Map<Integer, List<String>>` then he'll be moving around strings from one `List` to another, and that sort of defeats the purpose of using a `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: In this case, the correct is not a `Map<List<String>, Integer>`? Because diferrent String can have the same amount of words.

Comment: @Renato Its `Map<Integer, List<String>> wordCountToStringsMap`

Comment: `Integer` is the key and the `List<String>`, the values, right? So, if I have two differents String with the same count of words ("My name is Renato" and "I live in Brazil"), the two will have 4 as key. In this case, I will need to add the second phrase to the String list?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can go for LinkedHashMap.It preserves the order in which you entered

```
Map<String,Integer> map=new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>();
```

Then you can add and perform your operations.

Answer (score 0):

Well the Map  interface looks like what you'd need. The specific implementation should be LinkedHashMap, because you want to be able to retrieve the elements in the order you inserted them.

So you will have

```
Map <String, Integer> myMap = new LinkedHashMap <String, Integer> ();
```

then just add the lines, iterate over them with a for (String phrase : myMap.keys()) and do what you want with them!